# (node v8plus)example.c:5:26: fatal error: sys/ccompile.h: No such file or director

Tags: c, node.js, ubuntu

when I want to try out nodejs module 'v8plus' that lead to only use C to write nodejs addons, I try its example file, but it tell errors that is lacking files.
could anyone tell me that how to get these lacking library files and install? thanks.

all error codes output in ubuntu bash shell:

$ make

/usr/bin/gcc  -DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION -DMODULE=example -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DPIC -isystem /usr/local/bin/../include/node -I. -I/media/2/pro/v8plus/node_modules/v8plus -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -fPIC -O2 -std=c99 -c -o example.o example.c

example.c:5:26: fatal error: sys/ccompile.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

make: *** [example.o] Error 1

---

makefile all content:

```
V8PLUS = ..
include /media/2/pro/v8plus/node_modules/v8plus/Makefile.v8plus.defs
MODULE = example
MODULE_DIR = .
SRCS = \
example.c
ERRNO_JSON = errno.json
PREFIX_NODE = /opt/local
CC = /usr/bin/gcc
CXX = /usr/bin/g++
PREFIX_NODE := $(shell dirname bash -c 'hash node; hash -t node')/..
V8PLUS := $(shell $(PREFIX_NODE)/bin/node -e 'require("v8plus");')
include /media/2/pro/v8plus/node_modules/v8plus/Makefile.v8plus.targ
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v8plus is only compatible with illumos distros as noted in [the v8plus faq](https://github.com/joyent/v8plus#faq) ("What systems can I use this on?"). So you won't be able to get it to compile on Windows, Linux, BSD, or OS X for example without some major changes.